# Github showing entire file on Single Line

Tags: git, github, core.autocrlf

After committing in git bash, I went to verify the code on GitHub and noticed the file that changed looked like this:

```
<?php^M^Mrequire_once GLOBAL_INCLUDES . DS . "api.php";^M^Mclass MyAPI extends API {^M^Mprotected $User;   // continues for a long time on this line, a 1000 line file all to the right of this --->
```

Obviously this is a line ending issue with the `^M^M` (or at least I think this is obvious?)

I have since tried to normalize all of my lines in my entire project using github's instructions.  I did `git config --global core.autocrlf true` to no avail.

How can I resubmit the file (actually multiple files) to git/GitHub short of wiping my project and making a new repository?

Answer (score 1):

In my Netbeans IDE environment, I found a plug in that fixed this:

All of the problem files were "Mac OS 9 (CR)"

Changing them either to Unix (LF) or Windows (CRLF)  -- then committing and pushing to GitHub fixed the issue.

Comment: In eclipse: File -> Convert Line Delimiters To -> Unix fixed the problem